Compact Resolvent Operator for Schrodinger operator
I encounter problems with the compact operator shown in $L^{\infty}$.
Let $\rho \in C^{\infty}_c(-L,L)$, I want to first show $\rho R_0(\lambda)$, where $R_0(\lambda) = (-\Delta + \lambda^2)^{-1}$, is compact operator in $L^{\infty}$and then show that $(V+W)\rho R_0(\lambda)$ is compact operator in $L^{\infty}$, for $V, W$ compactly supported potential. Should I use the Ascoli-Azela or finite rank theorem? Or there's another way. If not possible, since my $W(x) = w(x)|u|^2u$ has cubic nonlinearity, we can not use $L^2$ as topology, Is there another better choice?
